# ESP32: dsb1820 temperature sensor giving constant negative 127 reading

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, sensors, esp32

I am trying to get a temperature reading using a single dsb1820 temperature sensor attached to an esp32 micro controller. The sensor is attached to GPIO-4 of the esp32. I intend to send the temperature reading to a cloud.

The problem i am facing is that the temperature reading always gives the value -127.

I read somewhere online that when the dsb1820 returns -127 it means that the sensor is not connected.

Am I using the wrong pin to connect the sensor?

[image: esp32 pinout]

```cpp
#include "OneWire.h"
#include "DallasTemperature.h"
#include <WiFi.h>
#define WIFI_SSID "SSID"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "PASSWORD"

OneWire oneWire(4);
DallasTemperature tempSensor(&oneWire);

void setup(void)
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
    Serial.print("Connecting to Wi-Fi");
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
        Serial.print(".");
        delay(300);
    }
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Connected with IP: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    Serial.println();

    tempSensor.begin();
}

void loop(void)
{
    tempSensor.requestTemperaturesByIndex(0);

    Serial.print("Temperature: ");
    Serial.print(tempSensor.getTempCByIndex(0));
    Serial.println(" C");

    delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: A funny reading like that is often because there is a short circuit - when this happened to me it was because the data wire was shorting on the power.

Comment: @HaydenEastwood, not necessary in the case of DS18B20, it usually means that OP is missing the resistor that is required between Vcc and output of DS18B20 or with a wrong resistor value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your cables and:

```
const int oneWireBus = 32;  // on pin 32 /GPIO7/D0 on pcb (a 4.7K resistor is necessary)
OneWire oneWire(oneWireBus);
```

and it should be the middle pin of the sensor (see my graphic)

[image: Connections to ESP32 - RESISTOR!]

**EDIT**
The DevKit has no pin 4 either you use GPIO4 (4 on the pcb) which is in Arduino 24 BUT

> The following strapping pins: 0, 2, 4, 5 (HIGH during boot), 12 (LOW
>   during boot) and 15 (HIGH during boot) are used to put the ESP32 into
>   bootloader or flashing mode. Don't connect peripherals to those pins!
>   If you do, you may have trouble trying to upload code, flash or reset
>   the board.

Connect to 32 (GPIO7 or D0 on the pcb) as this is safe for testing

If you have that wrong or no/**wrong** resistor it will give you -127 (or you killed the sensor/it was DOA).

Comment: i made the same circuit as shown in your picture with a 4.75 ohm ressistor. In fact i used the same exact picture as the one you posted for reference. The only thing different is my esp32 pinout is as shown in the picture i posted.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ill make sure the ressistor is 4.7kOhms. You stated that i should use GPIO7 for the sensor, What would i name it in the code? I mean instead of 4 written in my code should i write 7 , D0 or 0??