# esp32 getting temperature readings from ds18b20

Tags: microcontroller, sensors, esp32, arduino-esp32

I have run into some problems with the use of esp32 and dallas ds18B20 temperature sensors, as I can’t get readings out of them.

The esp32 is a DOIT ESP32 devkit v1 and the sensors are the standard type through the hole and/or the ones that have 1-1.5 meter cable and are watertight.

I suspect that it is library issue with the esp32 as the same libs work fine with arduino uno, mini etc. Cable connections have been checked many times. I have used the following libraries installed from inside arduino IDE:

1. OneWire by Paul Stoffregen v.2.3.6 (https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_OneWire.html)
2. DallasTemperature by Miles Burton v.3.9.0 (https://github.com/milesburton/Arduino-Temperature-Control-Library)

Could somebody please point out to me a working set of libraries that have been successful for you?

Edit: There is a similar question here:[ESP32: dsb1820 temperature sensor giving constant negative 127 reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61172204/esp32-dsb1820-temperature-sensor-giving-constant-negative-127-reading) but I don't think that it is solved.

Here is my includes and pin definition:

```
/************************* Dallas Temperature probes ********************************/
    #include <OneWire.h>
    #include <DallasTemperature.h>
    const int oneWireBus = 26;     // GPIO5 in esp32
    const int TEMPERATURE_PRECISION = 12; //12bit precision 0.01 steps
```

The resistor and setup is the same.

Comment: How are they wired to the ESP32? Did you use a pull-up resistor on the data line?

Comment: dallas pins: pin1 to GND, pin2 to esp32 and to 4K7 to 3V3, pin3 to 3V3

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why 26. Try:

```
const int oneWireBus = 5;     // GPIO5 in esp32
```

Complete code:

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
const int oneWireBus = 5;     // GPIO5 in esp32
const int TEMPERATURE_PRECISION = 12; //12bit precision 0.01 steps
OneWire onewire(oneWireBus);
DallasTemperature sensors(&onewire);

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  sensors.begin();
}
void loop(){
  sensors.requestTemperatures();
  temperature = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);
  Serial.println(temperature);
}
```

Comment: I tried it but i had no luck. I am rewiring the whole thing to see if it is a circuit problem.